# In django how to model an invoice which can have multiple items?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework in the backend and Angular for frontend.

If the customer order multiple items, it should be be in a single invoice. For example, if the customer order apple, orange and banana, all these should be in a single invoice.

When the customer order again and it will be a new invoice.

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoiceitems')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoiceitems')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_item = models.OneToOneField(
        InvoiceItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice')
```

Now I have to link the InvoiceItem with Invoice. I thought about using post_save signals with InvoiceItem as a sender to create Invoice object and link it with the InvoiceItem.

```
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=InvoiceItem)
def create_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Invoice.objects.update_or_create(invoice_item=instance)
```

How can I do it for multiple items?

Or there is a better way to implement my requirements?

Comment: A `OneToOneField` is, well, one to one. You must remove it and have a foreign key in the `InvoiceItem` class, i.e. `invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, ...)`.

Comment: You can use an JSONField in InvoceItem to save all products in one field. product as key and quantity as value.

Comment: How are getting the list of products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your approach.

First of all, your

```py
    invoice_item = models.OneToOneField(
        InvoiceItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice')
```

implies that there is only one type of `Product` per `Invoice`, i.e. having bought apples `Customer` can't buy also some oranges in the same `Invoice`.

If you try to fix that by creating `ForeignKey` on `InvoiceItem`, as others have already pointed out, you find yourself struggling with the second problem:

You attach `InvoiceItem` to a customer. Meaning that there's nothing stopping the system from creating a single `Invoice` that has 5 `Oranges`  bought by Alice as an `InvoiceItem` and 7 Apples bought by Bob as another `InvoiceItem`, which seems wrong.

I would also move the `date` field from `InvoiceItem` to `Invoice` and rename it to `timestamp`, as I assume an `Invoice` is a set of `Products` bought together at one time.

You would end up with something like this:

```py
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice_items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice_items')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoices')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now if you examine `related_name` arguments on the fields you'll see that you can do very useful things with your objects, like

```py
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=<some_id>)
customer.invoices
```

will give you a `QuerySet` of all the `Invoices` belonging to a specific `Customer`. And having an `Invoice` object you can

```py
invoice.invoice_items
```

to get all the items on an invoice

Or, for example, having a `Product`, say, `'apple'`, you can find all customers that ever bought an apple:

```py
# Find all invoice_items for apple
inv_items = apple_product.invoice_items.all()
# Filter Customers 
Customer.objects.filter(invoices__invoice_items__in=inv_items)
```

If you squint a little, you'll see that this whole structure is just a django M2M `through` relation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and can be rewritten like this:

```py
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice_items')
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice_items')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoices')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='InvoiceItem')
```

So now you have `Invoice` directly connected to `Products`, and this connection also contains information about the quantity of this `Product` on this `Invoice`. I will leave the exploration of the benefits of this approach to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ForeignKey` from the `InvoiceItem` to `Invoice`:

```py
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    ...
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ...
```

You should be able to then remove the `post_save`. You'll create items like this:

```
>>> invoice = Invoice.objects.create(<insert arguments here>)
>>> invoice_item = InvoiceItem.objects.create(invoice=invoice, <insert other arguments>)
>>> invoice_item.invoice.pk == invoice.pk
[out] True (i.e., the invoice item is attached to the invoice)
```